# Radical of Lie algebra after modding out by a semisimple ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, lie-algebras

Let $\mathfrak{g}$ be a Lie algebra, then Levi's decomposition theorem affirms that we can decompose $\mathfrak{g} = \mathfrak{r(g)}\oplus \mathfrak{s}$, where $\mathfrak{r(g)}$ is the [radical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radical_of_a_Lie_algebra) of $\mathfrak{g}$, and $\mathfrak{s}$ is a semisimple subalgebra of $\mathfrak{g}$.

I think this is easy, but I'm very stuck on this question

> **Question:** If  $\mathfrak{g}$ is a Lie algebra, with Levi's decomposition $\mathfrak{g} = \mathfrak{r(g)}\oplus \mathfrak{s}$, and $\mathfrak{s_0}$ is a semisimple ideal of $\mathfrak{g}$. Is it true that the Levi's decompostion of $\mathfrak{g}/\mathfrak{s_0} = \mathfrak{r_1}\oplus s_1$, satisfyies $\mathfrak{r(g)} \cong\mathfrak{r_1}$ ($\cong$ is the isomorfism of Lie Algebras)?

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Does this really have to do with the Levi decomposition? You're asking whether the radical of $\mathfrak{g} / \mathfrak{s}_0$ is isomorphic to the radical of $\mathfrak{g}$, right?

Comment: And in that case, I think the answer is positive, as a particular case of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2196404/radical-of-a-quotient-lie-algebra .

Comment: @darijgrinberg  you are right.

Comment: @darijgrinberg do you know why in the answer linked, here can write $ X=R(L)+X∩S$? In general, isn't true that $(V_1 \oplus V_2) \cap W = V_1 \cap W \oplus V_2 \cap W.$

Comment: Use both $L = R\left(L\right) + S$ and $R\left(L\right) \subseteq X$.