# Isomorphism of Lie algebra after modding out by a semisimple ideal.

Tags: linear-algebra, representation-theory, lie-algebras

Let $\mathfrak{g}$ be a Lie algebra, then Levi's decomposition theorem affirms that we can decompose $\mathfrak{g} = \mathfrak{r(g)}\oplus \mathfrak{s}$, where $\mathfrak{r(g)}$ is the [radical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radical_of_a_Lie_algebra) of $\mathfrak{g}$, and $\mathfrak{s}$ is a semisimple subalgebra of $\mathfrak{g}$.

> **Question:** If $\mathfrak{s_0}$ is a semisimple ideal of $\mathfrak{g}$ such that $\mathfrak{g}/\mathfrak{s_0}$ is a solvable Lie algebra, is it true that $\mathfrak{s_0}\cong \mathfrak{s} $ (isomorfism of Lie Algebras)?

Can anyone help me?

---

I was able to conclude that $\mathfrak{g/s_0} = \mathfrak{r (g/s_0)} \cong \mathfrak{r(g)}$ (by this question [Radical of a quotient Lie algebra](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2196404/radical-of-a-quotient-lie-algebra)), but I could not imply that $s_0 \cong \mathfrak s$ (the dimensions are the same but this doesn't imply that there is an isomorphism of Lie Algebras).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is true, consider $p_0:g\rightarrow g/s_0$, $p_0(s)$ is a semi-simple subalgebra of $g/s_0$, since $g/s_0$ is solvable, we deduce that $p_0(s)=0$ and $s\subset s_0$, a similar argument shows that $s_0\subset s$ by considering $p:g\rightarrow g/s$.

Comment: How do you know that $p_0 (\mathfrak{s})$ is semi-simple? This isn't clear to me.

Comment: Let $I$ be a simple ideal, $I=[I,I], p(I)=p([I,I])=[p(I),p(I)]$, since $g/s$ is solvable, $p(I)$ is solvable, we deduce that $p(I)=0$. $s$ is a sum of solvable ideal.

Comment: Thx very much to your help, I was very stuck on this problem, now I feel invincible. Very clean demonstration.

Comment: This seems to show that if $\mathfrak{s}$ is an ideal, then it is equal (not only isomorphic) to $\mathfrak{s}_0$. The question only assumes $\mathfrak{s}$ to be a subalgebra, so the quotient in your very last step is no Lie algebra and you cannot conclude as that.

Comment: It seems that instead a dimension argument might finish the proof and indeed show equality, not just isomorphism.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg I agree with you. Using the first part of the argumentation we conclude that $\mathfrak{s_0} \subset \mathfrak{s}$, using that $\text{dim}(\mathfrak{s_0})= \text{dim}(\mathfrak{s})$, imply that $\mathfrak{s_0}=\mathfrak{s}$.